# Validating Empty Squares TicTacToe - Javascript only

Tags: javascript

First I would like to say thank you to the individuals that helped me with this question before. For the ones that decided to close my post without even trying to first assist me, please refrain from closing my post if you are not deciding to help and calling my issue too broad. Also, I'm not looking as of this time to "optimize" my code or for corrections with how I expatiate my summary below. Now, for the real issue...

I'm trying my hand at building a tic-tac-toe game with plain vanilla Javascript, so I'm hoping we can stay in the boundaries of keeping it simple Javascript. Do not optimize code!

What I require is the following: I need code that will check each square to see if it's filled with an X or an O. If squares are still available, no need for an alert but if all squares are filled, I need it to alert me "No more moves!"

I have started the function checkEmpty

Thank you for your assistance and time!

Here is the code I have got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        td {

            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 150pt;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square1" onclick="displayMarker('square1');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square2" onclick="displayMarker('square2');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square3" onclick="displayMarker('square3');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square4" onclick="displayMarker('square4');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square5" onclick="displayMarker('square5');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square6" onclick="displayMarker('square6');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square7" onclick="displayMarker('square7');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square8" onclick="displayMarker('square8');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square9" onclick="displayMarker('square9');"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        var cp1 = 1;

        function displayMarker(allSquares) {

            if (document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML != "") {
                alert("Choose another square");
            }
            else {

                if (cp1 == 1) {
                    document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "X";
                    cp1 = 2;
                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "O";
                    cp1 = 1;
                }
            }
            checkEmpty();
        }
        function checkEmpty() {

            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                console.log(document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML + " square" + i);

            }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work:

```
function checkEmpty() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (!document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML) return;
    }
    alert("all squares filled");
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me James. It was to the point, short, sweet, and understandable. I was getting caught up in other code and wasn't being able to zone in on what you showed above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkEmpty() {
        var isEmpty = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            var squareVal = document.getElementById('square' + i).innerHTML;
            if(squareVal.length == 0)
            {
               isEmpty = true;
               break;
            }                               
        }

        if(!isEmpty)
        {
            alert('No more moves');
        }
    }
```